# ¿Como puedo controlar que se ha efectuado el login de FTP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, login, ftp

¿Hay algo que me pueda ayudar a saber si el login se ha efectuado o en cambio si no se ha efectuado, mandar un mensaje a mi log?

```
ftp = FTP(dirServer)
ftp.login(user=usuario, passwd=passwd)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un bloque [`try`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) para detectar el error y en el bloque `except` verificas el código de login incorrecto usando [`ftplib.all_errors`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.all_errors):

```
import ftplib # Importa la librería completa
#...

try:
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(dirServer)
    ftp.login(usuario, passwd)
except ftplib.all_errors as e:
    codigo_error = str(e).split(None, 1)[0] # Extraer el código de error
    if codigo_error == '530': # Código 530: Login incorrecto
        #Logica para guardar log
        print('Login incorrecto')
```

Comment: he probado esto que me has comentado, y no doy con ello creo que no me devuelve el codigo 530.